# How to get info on CleaCase merge arrow

Tags: merge, clearcase

I have a file in ClearCase that has merge arrow from branch X to branch main.
These was no real merge only draw merge arrow.
Is there a way to get info about it, like when and which user did it ?
I checked file history including minor events but the info wasn't available.

Answer (score 1):

A `cleartool dump` [as used here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/identifying-elements-source-container-path) would only give you information like `id/source/destination`, but nothing regarding authorship or creation date.

So if it is not in the history (even minor), check if describing ([`cleartool describe`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm)) the version is enough to get the hyperlink id:

```sh
M:\default_view\DemoVOB>cleartool describe -long tweedledee.txt@@\main\1
version "M:\default_view\DemoVOB\tweedledee.txt@@\main\1"
  created 27-Sep-04.14:21:23 by jdoe.Domain Users@host1
  Element Protection:
    User : DOMAIN_1\jdoe : r--
    Group: DOMAIN_1\Domain Users : r--
    Other:          : r--
  element type: text_file
  predecessor version: \main\0
  Hyperlinks:
    Merge@125@\DemoVOB <- M:\default_view\DemoVOB\tweedledee.txt@@\main\testing\1
    ^^^^^^^^^
```

From there, you can describe the hyperlink itself:

```sh
cleartool describe hlink:Merge@516262@/vobs_proj 
hyperlink "Merge@516262@/vobs_proj"
 created 2006-07-14T16:43:35 by Bill Bo (bill.user@uranus)
 Merge@516262@/vobs_proj /vobs_proj/lib/cvt/cvt_cmd.c@@/main/v1.1_port/8 ->
 /vobs_proj/lib/cvt/cvt_cmd.c@@/main/71
```

Comment: Thanks. I successfully got info on merge arrow using cleartool describe -long.
But when I run this cleartool describe hlink:Merge@516262@/vobs_proj I don't get info on the merge, instead it seems I get info on the file i.e. 
master replica, owner and group. Any ideas what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @Epligam Not sure: maybe this hyperlink is not the right one.